# Entity Framework data persistance

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 entities A and B. They are not related.

```
public partial class A
{
   public string code { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
}
```

In case of entity B, I have extended it by using a partial class in order to put a navigation property pointing to entity A:

```
public partial class B 
{
   public A customExtProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have an object c of type B and I perform below statements on it (I update some properties):

```
public void UpdateCustomProperties(B c)
{
    c.customExtProperty = dbContext.A.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == "9999");
    c.customExtProperty.code = myCutomCode;
    c.customExtProperty.description = myCustomDescription;
}
```

Taking account above piece of code I have below doubts:

- Do the changes on code and descrition fields be applied to the model? or is it only applied to the object c itself?
- If from another process I perform dbContext.A.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == "9999"), will I get the code and description fields updated with above values myCutomCode and myCustomDescription respectively?

Comment: Regarding your first question; What do you mean with 'applied to the model'. After creating the partial class B you will need to update your model by creating a migration and then applying that to your database.

Comment: @Hintham I mean changes are applied to dbContext.A but not to the physical database table (database is only applied after doing context.SaveChanges()).

Answer (score 1):

> a partial class in order to put a navigation property pointing to entity A:

There is nothing different about a navigation property defined in a partial class definition.  It's a regular navigation property.

> Do the changes on code and descrition fields be applied to the model? or is it only applied to the object c itself?

If c is [tracked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) by the DbContext, then the changes to c will be applied to the database when you call DbContext.SaveChanges().  And after that the change will be visible to other processes and other DbContext instances.